# When uitableviewcell is clicked seque to viewcontroller and fill uitextfield with the text in the cell selected swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, segue

I'm trying to make it so when I click a tableviewcell in my tableviewcontroller it segues to another viewcontroller and uses the text that was in the cell and automatically fills the uitextfield in the controller that it was segued too.

I was thinking it would start from this method

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}
```

[Exercise TableView Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iimbi.png)

Clicked in this controller and uses the text in the cell

[Add Exercise TableView Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMXxb.png)

Fills the exercise uitextfield with text

In Swift btw. Thanks.

Comment: You should show more effort, what exactly have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have done this before and it does require a fairly decent amount of code, you need to research into this more because right now you aren't even close

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Create a Segue in the storyboard and give it an identifier("YourSegue")

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  let text = "Your text"
    performSegueWithIdentifier("YourSegue", sender: text)
}
```

> 2. Then Call This function

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                if segue.identifier == "YourSegue" {
                   let yourOtherVC = segue.destinationViewController as? YourOtherViewController
                if let text = sender as? String {
                yourOtherViewController?.text = text    
       }  
     } 
    }
```

> 3. Put this variable in the ViewController that you want to show(YourOtherViewController).

```
var text: String

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad() 

if text != nil {
yourTextField.text = text

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only issue is in my YourOtherViewController I get the issue "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer"? Is it because of the fact that it's not an optional for the nil?

Comment: Hi @Nate Grant, can you paste the entire error? But try this (if text != nil { yourTextField.text = text} else { print("Something")}.

Comment: And (var text: String!)